# How to specify constructor value on resolved concrete type using Unity IoC?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've seen a lot of posts asking about *which* overloaded constructor to select using Unity, but my question is a little different and I can't figure out the answer. I have the following class inheriting an Interface (partial code):

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

}
```

So now I'm trying to use unity to resolve the concrete type to the interface like below:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

However, I need to pass in my Entity Framework context to that concrete type upon being resolved. I *want* to do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork(new AdventureWorks2008R2Entities())>();
```

Of course I know the code above is incorrect, and have read about using the `InjectionConstructor` class, but I don't think that's applicable here.

So my question is, how do I define the value of that constructor on the `UnitOfWork` class when resolving the concrete type using Unity IoC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the `InjectionConstructor` class as I had inteded and the following registration worked well:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new InjectionConstructor(new AdventureWorks2008R2Entities()));
```

The following link helped me understand this a bit better:

[Registering Injected Parameter and Property Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a registration for a DbContext: `container.RegisterType<DbContext, AdventureWorks2008R2Entities>();`

Remember, one major feature of an IoC container is to auto-wire.  You don't need to tell each registration what instance to use.  You just register interfaces/classes to implementations and let it put stuff in the right place (and override in the ideally rare occasions where you're doing something abnormal).